# Programmatically setting the image of a UIButton based on the image stored at a specific index in an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, nsarray

Difficult to explain this question. I am attempting to create a set of `UIButtons` on screen which is based on the number of entries in an `NSArray`. I have created an `NSArray` containing a number of images, like so:

```
socialArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"FacebookButton.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"WebsiteSocialButton.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"TumblrButton.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"TwitterButton.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"InstagramButton.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"VimeoButton.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"GooglePlusButton.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"YouTubeButton.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PinterestButton.png"],
                  nil];
```

and am creating the number of items in the view based on that, like so:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [socialArray count];
}
```

I am then programatically creating the button and setting its image, like so:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{ 
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
    if (button == nil)
    {
        //no button available to recycle, so create new one
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    //set button label
    [button setTitle:[socialArray objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return button;
}
```

What I really want to do is set the image of the button based on the specified image in an array. So, the first button gets the PNG file specified at index 0, second button gets image at index 1 and so on.

Any advice on how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [socialArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

(You have to do this outside of the `if` statement, otherwise the image wouldn't be set for buttons that are reused.)

Comment: The array is an `UIImage` array, not NSStrings.

Comment: I had already tried that method. It crashes with the following: NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfe46100

Answer (score 0):

Get it from the array:

```
UIImage *image = [socialArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do:
    `UIImage *image = [socialArray objectAtIndex:index];` ?

If `index` may get bigger than your array, then change it to:

```
UIImage *image = [socialArray objectAtIndex:(index % [self numberOfItemsInCarousel:carousel])];
```

Comment: The array is an `UIImage` array, not NSStrings.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
int i=0;
    if (button == nil)
    {
        //no button available to recycle, so create new one
        UIImage *image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:i];
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        i++;

    }
```

Comment: this will set the image of first button with that of first element of array, and increment with one, but try also  make sure that this incremental doesn't exceeds the array count

Comment: Hi. That just crashes the application with the following - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xce79fb0'

Comment: u are trying to call image's wrong method, use socialArray as ur array, not image